# laravel Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded --

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

hello guys so I am doing a laravel project ( new to laravel ).
i am supposed to to calculation from other tables and save the results in another OUTPUT table.
I have 8 calculation in total in each line and up to 3k lines to fill.
The problem that I get the ma execution time error 60 sec even if a change it in laravel and php.ini.
each function called is just calling a select where and sum I've decided to divide them for better org.
My question is is there a better way to process the data and minimize to exc time if you can help .

```
public function calcul($week)
    {   $test = Output::where('week',$week)->Limit(1);
        if($test->first()){
            return self::afficher($week);

        }
        else{
            
            DB::table('article')->orderBy('material')->chunk(100, function ($stocks){
           
            foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
                $id = $stock->material;
                $safe_stock=self::safe_stock($id);
                $past_need=self::PassedNeeds($id) - self::NeedsInTwoWeeks($id);
                $two_week_need=self::NeedsInTwoWeeks($id);
                $stock_=self::stock($id);
                $bdl=self::bdl($id);
                $sm=self::sm($id);
                $package=self::package($id);
               
                $store_1=self::store_1($id);
                $store_2=self::store_2($id);
                $store_3=self::store_3($id);
                Output::create([
                    'material' => $id,'safe_stock'=>$safe_stock,'past_need'=>$past_need,'two_week_need'=>$two_week_need,
                    'stock'=>$stock_,'bdl'=>$bdl,'sm'=>$sm,'package'=>$package,
                    'store_1'=>$store_1,'store_2'=>$store_2,'store_3'=>$store_3
                ]);
            }
            });
          
            return self::index();
           
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think it gets slow because you are doing a loop, and doing DB-inserts in that loop. Usually you want to prevent this kind of behavior. If you just add the array in `Output::create()` into a bigger array, `$bulk[] = [/* array you now put in Output::create() */]` and then do `Output::insert($bulk)`, you reduce the amount of queries by 100. Just make sure you define `$bulk = []` at the beginning of your chunk so it gets cleaned every iteration.

Comment: i've tried that but its the same problem ive chunked and then put the results in array then insert them but its  the same. the problem is the functions I call to calculate each time that takes time . if you have another suggestion to try I will appreciate it and thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Allright, how many results are you parsing? I mean if you have thousands of records to parse, 60 seconds wont be enough no matter how fast the code is :) If it is too big of a bulk, you can use `set_time_limit($x)` if $x == 0, it wont time out at all. If you don't like that solution, you can also make a command, and put the code in there. This solution is very use-case-depentant, so not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: thank you @RobBiermann it worked for me but the process takes around 10 min I will try to find a way to make it take less time.